# Is there any way to determine if we have fully consumed a CLOSED Kinesis shard other than by trying to read from it?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-kinesis

Each Shard in the ListShards response includes an [`EndingSequenceNumber`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/kinesis/latest/APIReference/API_SequenceNumberRange.html#Streams-Type-SequenceNumberRange-EndingSequenceNumber) that I originally thought could be used to determine whether we have fully consumed a CLOSED shard by comparing it to the sequence number of the last record we have read.

But from testing this out, it looks like `EndingSequenceNumber` may not be equal to the sequence number of the last record in the shard but appears to be always greater than it.

Does `EndingSequenceNumber` encode the sequence number of the last record in the shard or are there any other guarantees around it?

Otherwise, are there any other ways to determine if we have fully consumed a shard just based on the sequence number of the last record we have read instead of actually reading the shard and checking if [`event.ContinuationSequenceNumber == null` for SubscribeToShard](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/streams/latest/dev/building-enhanced-consumers-api.html) or [`NextShardIterator` == null for GetRecords](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/kinesis/latest/APIReference/API_GetRecords.html#Streams-GetRecords-response-NextShardIterator)?

Note: I am using the SDK and not the KCL so I would prefer a solution based on the SDK.

Thanks!